# Get independent HTML from $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume that in

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page1.html',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        $(data)  //return an array of nodes
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

`$(data)` returns an array of nodes:

```
[<div id="a">,
 <div id="b">,  //3 elements
 <div id="c">]
```

and I want to get the HTML of the div that has an `id` of `"b"`. I tried

```
$(data).find("#b");
```

but it returns a blank array. (`[]`) So how can I select it? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to select from top level elements.
- Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to selected nested elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(data).filter('#b')
```

you should use filter instead of find, since there's no parent element for all of those elements so no higher level context to find from.